# Is there a pythonic way to remove offsets that are contained within larger offsets?

Tags: python

I have a list of offsets -

```
input = [(157, 1228), (1233, 1540), (1925, 7000), (2392, 4378), (4451, 5368), (5759, 7000)]
```

I want to keep only those offsets that are not contained in other offsets. For example:

```
output = [(157, 1228), (1233, 1540), (1925, 7000)]
```

I tried for-loops and if-else statements, but I am sure there would be a pythonic way to compute this.

I have tried this -

```
for i in range(1,len(x),1):
    if x[i-1][1] > x[i][0]:
        del x[i]
```

But this does not work.

Comment: What does "not contained in other subsets" mean? you should still show what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def is_offset_contains_offset(offset1, offset2):
    return offset1[0] <= offset2[0] and offset1[1] >= offset2[1]

input = [(157, 1228), (1233, 1540), (1925, 7000), (2392, 4378), (4451, 5368), (5759, 7000)]
output = []

for curr_offset in input:
    if not any(is_offset_contains_offset(good_offset, curr_offset) for good_offset in output):
        output.append(curr_offset)

print(output)
```

Comment: You can edit is_offset_contains_offset func to do what Marcos did, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

(removed old attempt - not sure about it's validity)

EDIT (new answer - order independant) & hopefully getting closer to the pythonic way - but more iterations to make it order independant:

```
def check_if_outside(offset, offset_input):
    return not any((i[0] < offset[0] < i[1]) or (i[0] < offset[1] < i[1]) for i in {el for el in offset_input}.difference({offset}))

# Now (to prove order isn't important) reorder the sample
sample = [(2392, 4378), (157, 1228), (1233, 1540), (1925, 7000), (4451, 5368), (5759, 7000)]

result = list(filter(lambda x: check_if_outside(x, sample), sample))
```

Comment: @JasonChia - look better now?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this simple `for` looping if both edges are contained:

```py
sample = [
    (157, 1228), (1233, 1540), (1925, 7000), (2392, 4378), (4451, 5368), (5759, 7000)
]

output = []
for x, y in sample:
    if not any(
            (x > i[0] and x < i[1]) or (y > i[0] and y < i[1]) for i in output
    ):
        output.append((x,y))

print(output)

>>> [(157, 1228), (1233, 1540), (1925, 7000)]
```

Also, you shouldn't use the word `input` as a variable name, which is a `python` reserved keyword that handles user input functionality.